# Groupby apply method on a column not returning correct results

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have the following dask dataframe containing among others the following columns:

```
raw_data.head()

     http_user              dst  dst_port
0      user1      1.1.1.1            80
1      user1      2.2.2.2           443
2      user2      3.3.3.3            80
3      user3      4.4.4.4           443
4      user2      5.5.5.5            80
```

I do the following action

```
groups = raw_data.groupby(['http_user', 'dst', 'dst_port'])
my_feature = groups.http_method.apply(lambda x: 'CONNECT' in x.values', meta=('name', '?')
```

Trying to calculate `my_feature.head()` gives me very strange results

```
    http_user  dst  dst_port                
     10         -    "domain_name_string1"       False
                     "domain_name_string2"       False
                     "domain_name_string3"       False
                     "domain_name_string4"       False
```

It seems like groupby apply mixes columns.  Applying the same thing on the dataframes after computing works as it should Unfortunatelly I haven't been able to reproduce it locally. 
Also if I apply common aggregations on the column like

```
groups.http_method.max().compute()
```

produces correct results. With correct values of `http_user` `dst` and `dst_port`

`raw_data` contains approx 2.5K rows.

Is this a bug? Anybody seen this behaviour?

Comment: I recommend using github for bug reports.  If you're able to create a minimal reproducible example that would be ideal.

Comment: Unforturnatelly I cannot. Locally the dummy data work. I am not sure if it is the data or the action. Probably the action since common aggregations work. I am not sure it is a bug, first of all it is a question :)

Comment: Minor: in the second code block you are missing a n apostrophe before *dst* ie you want 'dst' not dst'.  This is messing up the formatting.